# How do I get geopandas to work on Windows 10 with WinPython?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, shapely, geopandas

I'm using WinPython with Python 3.6 on Windows 10 and through a long and winding course I managed to get geopandas installed and working properly on my system.  This required manually installing various dependencies like GDAL, Fiona, and PyProj, but it eventually worked fine.

A few days later (during which the computer was asleep) I'm trying to run the same code that worked fine and now I'm getting

```
Could not find lib geos_c.dll or load any of its variants
```

on the code `import geopandas as gp` when it gets to `from shapely.geos import lgeos`.  I have confirmed that I DO have shapely installed (via pip) and I have `geos_c.dll`, but it's looking here

```
C:\\WinPython\\python-3.6.5.amd64\\Library\\lib\\geos_c.dll'
```

while the file is actually here:

```
C:\\WinPython\\python-3.6.5.amd64\\Lib\\site-packages\\osgeo
```

In fact, I don't even have a `Library` directory in my python folder.

So I reinstalled Shapely, but this time using a whl file, and the error changed to `module 'shapely' has no attribute 'affinity'`,when called by `import geopandas`. Running `from shapely import affinity` causes no error. I don't know why these packages are so hard to install or get working but I'd sure like to know ....

> How do I get geopandas to work on Windows 10 with WinPython?

Or really, since it worked a few days ago, and nothing should have changed while the computer was sleeping, how to get it to work again like it used to?

Comment: I recommend to use Anaconda / conda installer, which includes built binaries for all the dependencies of GeoPandas, without the need to compile anything yourself.

Comment: Is there a way to use Anaconda / conda installer while still using the Winpython installation of Python?

Comment: I know it's not probably the answer you want, but I'd suggest installing vanilla Python, creating a virtualenv for your project, and installing Shapely, GDAL, PyProj and Fiona from the wheels at https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ in it, then trying `pip install geopandas`...

Comment: @AaronBramson no, Anaconda is a standalone python installation, similar as WinPython is, so I don't think you can combine them.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think so either, but I thought (hoped) conda-forge may actually be a library that could be installed separately.

Comment: The problem might be a bug in GDAL.  The solution for me was keeping a previous version of GDAL, so not allowing other packages to update it (geopandas might be trying to update GDAL).  If that is the problem, you can track a solution here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51959128/installation-of-gdal-with-conda-on-windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I should just delete my question, but the "solution" was to **restart my Python IDE**.  Restarting the kernel within Spyder didn't change anything, but I closed Spyder down completely and just reran the same without changing anything and it ran fine.  I don't know if any of the changes I made actually helped (since, like I said, it was working perfectly a few days ago).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to download the wheels for shapely and install manually. You can download the wheels from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#shapely (choose python version 36 and 32 or 64 bit windows).

Then install with:

```
pip install Shapely‑1.6.4.post1‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: Gohlke's site says "Chances are they do not work with custom Python distributions included with [...] WinPython etc.", so OP's mileage may vary since he's using WinPython.

Comment: Actually, I did this immediately after posting the question, and then I updated my question.

Comment: Ah thanks, I didn't know that. I always thought that WinPython was just clean Python with some packages and IDE's pre-installed. Still worth the try I would say.

Answer (score 0):

Rename goes_c to goes, it will end up working.